# A css question ( flex-basis: 0; ) frome chrome 90

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

After I update chrome to 90.0.4430.85, I found some UI in my program is changed.
for example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<style>
  .content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .item1 {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
  }
  
  .item2 {
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="item1">item1</div>
    <div class="item2">item2</div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

`item1` will be 400px height on chrome89, but it is 0px height on chrome90. I have to change `height: 200px;` to `min-height: 200px` to fix it. Why was this happened? And is there a specification to explain this?

Comment: This is more a hypothesis than an answer, so I'm going to leave it here for now. Your `flex-direction` property indicates that the primary axis is _vertical_. If the `flex-basis` corresponds with the primary axis (I'm fairly certain it does), then it will - and should - override the `height` (rather than overriding the `width` as it would if the primary axis were horizontal). For some reason in **Chrome 89**, `flex-basis` was not overriding `height`. **Chrome 90** corrects this oversight.